# Finding all web services in java web project (wsdl)

Tags: java, web-applications, wsdl

I have a simple and straight forward question. I have to find all the web services that are on my java web project (which uses wsdl's). My approach was to open all the wsdl's and see which service each calls, but I don't know if that's a correct approach to finding all the services. Also my project doesn't deploy, I'm finding all the services to see if they are being used or not and to see what is their purpose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the wsdls seems reasonable.

Also, look in the web.xml to see that the Web service servlet is defined there.

You can also look for annotations on classes such as

@ApplicationPath("/rest")
@Path("/myapp")

but that is for REST style services.